# JavaScriptとCSSのアニメーションはどちらが速い？

Tags: javascript, css

例えば横移動のアニメーションをする際、どちらが速いのでしょうか？

- transitionプロパティを使ったアニメーション
- requestAnimationFrameでtransform:translate3D等を動かしたアニメーション

速さ = FPS が良い方を知りたいです。

例えばスペックの悪いデバイス等でも、
FPSが高いのはどちらなのかなという疑問からの
質問でした。

Comment: なんの早さを知りたいのでしょうか? 開発の早さ?

Comment: 仮に「アニメーションの動作速度」であるなら、いずれもプロパティやコード等で時間を指定するようなので、**設計次第** という答えになりそうです。

Answer (score 1):

CSS transition と `requestAnimationFrame()` の双方とも、ハードウェアのリフレッシュレートに従って描画が更新されます。よって、CPUが十分に速ければどちらでもFPSは同じになります。

CPUが遅かったりアニメーション処理や他の処理が重いとき、`requestAnimationFrame()` のほうがFPSが落ちやすくなります。ブラウザのネイティブコードとJavaScriptの世界を橋渡しするためのオーバヘッドが常に存在するからです。